# Is it possible to set a 1d array to a tensorflow 2 model with tflite?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tflite

I am trying to use a **Keras** model saved in **tflite** in **C#**.
For preformance constraints, I would like to have a **1D array** as an input to my model.

But Keras always seems to add a dimension before for the batch size:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(128)
```

```bash
Model: "model_2"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 128)]        0
```

I then export it to **tflite** using the following:

```py
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(keras_model)
model_lite = converter.convert()
with open("model.tflite", "wb") as f:
  f.write(model_lite)
```

When I upen my tflite model, the dimension is `(1, 128)` I haven't found a way to make it `128`

Here it is **None**, I can set it to **1** but the first dimension remains, I am not sure how to discard it, there seems to be no way to do this in the tensorflow documentation.

I use:
**tensorflow-2.6.5** and **python 3.7.5**